# How to reorder Gridview rows using Jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am using Drag and Drop for sorting rows of grid,

In this process i want Order(Sequence) of dragged row to be changed dynamically like if i drag 3rd row to 1st place i want it(order) to change to 1 dynamically.

I am not getting any idea of how to loop and change order dynamically.

```
var SortedIDs = "";
$(".gvSortPorts").find("tbody > tr").each(function () {
    SortedIDs += $(this).attr("id") + "1";
});
```

Can any one please help in giving idea, i want it acheive using jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are number of jquery plugin available for sorting:

i have use [Datatable](http://www.datatables.net/)  which provide you a way which will help you alot.
you can do customization as you want and it provides number of features like pagging, search, sorting etc.

Hope this will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following JQuery and Tablesorter javascript files references inside page head section.

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Finally call the tablesorter function on gridview to make your gridview sortable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#GridView1").tablesorter();

   });
</script>
```

**Reference:**

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=2168345

**For Drag And Drop:**

http://forums.asp.net/t/1615668.aspx/1

Hope its helpful.